# NSDateFormatter converting rails string to NSDate returns nil?

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to convert a `datetime` passed from a rails api into an `NSDate` object so I can style it. I'm using `NSDateFormatter` and here is what I'm currently trying, I keep getting `nil` returned though, I've looked at some of the existing answers from other questions and adjusted but haven't been able to get it to work yet.

My code is as follows:

```
NSString *dateStr = @"2016-06-06 10:45:13 UTC";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
```

Comment: `2016-06-06 10:45:13 UTC` ... this is not right format date I think  .. this shold be included in date pattern http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It always helps to use your dateFormatter to turn known dates into strings to check, but I think you want: `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z"` (with a lowercase z).

See: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Comment: Worked perfectly thanks! and thanks for the link have bookmarked.